# Strange json.decoder.JSONDecodeError in spite of correct JSON

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm using json.loads in order to convert a list in a string to a list. (The list gets converted to a string during data transfer). I am receiving the exception: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 43 (char 42).

Essentially, the code goes as follows:

```
...

string_list = [["select", "What is your age?", [{"18+": True}, {"Below 18": False}], {"boolean": True}, {"application": ["basic", "all"]}, "age"], "18+", True]

replaced_str = str(string_list).replace("'",'"')

data = json.loads(replaced_str)

return data

...
```

The odd thing is, this list:

```
[["text", "What is your name?", {"question_application": ["basic", "all"]}], "utetwo"]
```

Works perfectly.

Here is the full error traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
StopIteration: 42

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/runner/Giftsling-Prototype-primary-1/main.py", line 129, in searchinput
    print(sh.generate_user_attributes(session['user_id']))
  File "/home/runner/Giftsling-Prototype-primary-1/main.py", line 260, in generate_user_attributes
    d = json.loads(dea)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 43 (char 42)
```

I am unable to find any questions about this issue elsewhere. I've followed all the steps that have fixed the issues of others, to no avail.

Comment: What is `h`? Make sure your code demonstrates the error before posting it. And show us the **full** error traceback.

Comment: @KlausD. My apologies, I've fixed the code and added the traceback.

Comment: Simply replacing single quotation marks with double quotation marks is not enough to make a Python list JSON. Always use `json.dumps()`. But frankly: what sense does it make to convert to JSON and back?

Comment: @KlausD. Essentially, I was trying to convert a list which was converted to a string back into a list, I was told it would be best to go about that by using json.dumps. Are there alternative ways to convert a "string list" to a list?

Comment: JSON and python are similar but not the same. For instance, you were tripped up by python's `True` verses JSON's `true`. There is no guarantee that using `str` on a python object will get you something that can be turned back into an object later. If you do `str(some_data_structure)` your best bet for getting python back is `ast.literal_eval` which decodes legal python.

Comment: You are better off doing `json.dumps(string_list)` if you want to save it for decode later. The dump will fail if the python object is not json serializable.